# CSS fixed background-attachment blinks in google chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, background-attachment

There is a Google chrome bug with my code that there isn't in IE & Firefox.
The Address is : [chashnik](http://chashnik.com/home)
The DIV class '.health' has a background image with fixed attachment property.
In Google chrome this images blinks repeatedly and never stopped.
There isn't any problem with Firefox & IE.
CSS Code:

```
.health {
    float: left;
    height: 930px;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    background-attachment:fixed !important;
    background-image: url(../images/pattern/back-healt.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Comment: i cant find anything strange, My chrome Version `31.0.1650.63 m`

Comment: @PrasanthKC toggle down and see on the left side

Comment: @Mr.Alien Is it that the bg with Cauliflower and tomato, if so there is nothing unusual for me, it works fine

Comment: blinks for me.. though am not solving as it's chrome...

Comment: @PrasanthKC I have the same version of chrome and its blinks clearly.

Comment: @user3159925 Is it?? but its perfect for me, dont know whats really happening.

Comment: For those who don't see it: scroll down the the last orange section, you will see the vegetables background flashing every few seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The carousel at the top of your page uses hardware acceleration in Chrome. Every time it changes the slide, the HW kicks in and it changes the way the page renders, slightly (including messing up anything that is `fixed`)

- Either you **replace the carousel** with something that doesn't make use of 3D transforms, or
- You **stop the carousel**, temporarily (after the user scrolls below it) or completely (which I suggest doing, considering how annoying both of them are)